# SQL to find almost identical values

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am looking for a sql-query to identify product numbers in a table that is almost identical. The only difference between some of the product numbers is that "/" is replaced with "-", at the exact same position in product number.

Example 1:

```
Product number: ab345-2
Product number: ab345/2
```

Example 2:

```
Product number: z0059966-98
Product number: z0059966/98
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us which SQL query/queries you have tried?

Comment: You can use REGEXP to select the ones that match and either have a - or /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self join the table to get each pair of duplicates in one row:

```
select 
  t1.product_number,
  t2.product_number
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on replace(t1.product_number, '-', '/') = t2.product_number
where t1.product_number like '%-%'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h9PZZBCFqVroWzXJXiVr2J/2).
Results:

```
| product_number | product_number |
| -------------- | -------------- |
| ab345-2        | ab345/2        |
| z0059966-98    | z0059966/98    |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where replace(replace(t2.product_number, '/', ''), '-') = replace(replace(t2.product_number, '/', ''), '-') and
                    t2.product_number <> t1.product_number
             );
```

Note that this can find matches to number that are missing these characters, such as `'ab345-2'` and `'ab3452'`.  Also, it removes all the special characters, so they can be in any position.